# Caching Spring data rest requests

Tags: java, caching, spring-data-rest

Currently we are using spring data rest for a project and I realised that spring data rest is very slowly when it converts the response using hateoas due to the list of returned elements is quite long.

I think if I could cache this response it would be the solution because the list will not change. So I enable the cache in the repository and it works fine, don't repeat the sql query, but it doens't solve the issue. The waste of time is not in the database query but in the hateoas transformation process.

Is there a way for caching http request in spring-data-rest, and not only the database access?

My current configuration is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class AvantBackendApplication extends 
SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ....


@Cacheable("towns")
public List<TownEntity> findAllByProvince(@Param("province") Integer province);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of request is it?  GET? POST?  For `GET` you may just have to configure the `cache-control` header, telling the browsers, proxies and servers in between you and the caller that they're allowed to cache the response.

Comment: the request is get. so it makes sense and could solve my issue. But anyway it could be possible to configure spring-data-rest as I was asking. I mean, if I used a controller class I guess I could annotate the method with @Cacheable and it would work. Is there anyway with spring-data-rest directly?

Comment: If you use a database have a look at PagingAndSortingRepository so you dont need to convert all entries of database into json.

Comment: @benkuly I need to return all rows because they are select options and it can't be paged . There are only about 100 rows, and it takes more or less 2 seconds, I think is a bit slow.